Angular Springboot Chat Implementation Error
How to resolve this error, i want to load chat from mysql database
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2222:25
at proto. [as open] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:782:16)
 url = 'http://localhost:8080';

  loadChat(){
    this.messages = this.http.post<Array<ChatMessage>>(this.url+'/getMessages' ,  this.roomName);
    this.messages.subscribe(data => {
      let mgs:Array<ChatMessage> = data;
      mgs.sort((a, b) => (a.ms_id > b.ms_id) ? 1 : -1)
      this.messages = of(mgs);
    })
    console.log(this.messages);
  }

chats are saved in database but i can't get i got this error
get,post methods are tried

This error has nothing to do with the database. Invalid urlmeans that the url you provided in the open method is not correct. Take a look at it.
